# This is a case to use instanceof?

Tags: java, instanceof

I have a class called `Document` that can be extended by `Page` or `Image`. For each one I have an insert method in database. The insert for `Page` and `Image` includes the insert for `Document`.

My doubt is if the way to determine what method will be called is verifying the class first, like this:

```
if (doc instanceof Document){
    insertDoc(doc);
}
if (doc instanceof Page){
    insertPage(doc);
}
if (doc instanceof Image){
    insertImage(doc);
}
```

Or there is another way, because I always heard that using `instanceof` is not a good thing.

**Edit:** Polymorphism doesn't works in this case, right? Something like `insert(Document doc)`, `insert(Page doc)` and `insert(Image doc)`.

Answer (score 8):

I think it would be better to implement the insert method in the `Document` class and override it with an appropriate methods in the classes that extend it. Then, just call `doc.insert();`.

Comment: I understand your solution, but I don't know if is the best option because I'm separating all in layers (view, TOs, data, core, etc). If I use ths way, this will break this organization, but it is a way that will work. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

In case that in future you plan to add more types that extend Document and add more operations than just insert(), I would suggest implementing a [Visitor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) design pattern . Otherwise, follow Bynyamin Sharet's suggestion.

Comment: I will study this solution more deep and see if is the best choice. Thank you.

Comment: I think that this approach is more correct from the architectural point of view.Good Luck!   ;)